# How to preserve precision of Bigdecimal in Java?

Tags: java

I am using xs:decimal as Type in XSD with length as

```
value="9999999999999999.999999999999999"

BigDecimal big = new BigDecimal("0.000000000001");
System.out.println(big); // Actual 1e-12 Expected 0.000000000001
```

i cannot use `toPlainString()`, since i want it in `BigDecimal`

Comment: [`BigDecimal.toPlainString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString%28%29)

Comment: What do you want ? You changed your question, now this doesn't make sense. Keep `big` if you want a `BigDecimal`, use `big.toPlainString()`,  if you want a `String` representation of it (without exponant)

Comment: i need decimal representation of the value. i am using this bigdecimal object in parsing it to XSD using JaxB marshaller. i am getting exponential form in output XML

Comment: And what is the problem with `toPlainString()` ? It is providing you the decimal representation in a `String` ...

Answer (score 1):

From the javadoc : [`BigDecimal.toPlainString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString%28%29)

> public String toPlainString()
>
> Returns a string representation of this BigDecimal without an exponent field.

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("0.000000001");
System.out.println(bd);
System.out.println(bd.toPlainString());
```

Will output :

```
1E-9
0.000000001
```